# Extract single messages from gmail thread (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, parsing, gmail, imap

I am trying to fetch gmail emails with IMAP (in objective-c), and I want to separate, for every thread, every single message that has been sent in the conversation. To make myself more clear, imagine a conversation like this one:

John says : Hi Mike, that's the first email
Mike replies : Hey John, how are you ?
John replies : Great Mike, thanks.

If I get John's emails through IMAP, I will fetch only one email, that will be :
     Hey John, how are you ?
     On Wed, 21 May, 
       Hi Mike, that's the first email

And I would like to get two different messages out of this *one* email I fetched.
First message would be "Hi Mike, that's the first email"
Second message would be "Hey John, how are you ?"

I looked at the message-id field in the header, but I can't figure out how to link that back to actual messages.

Any ideas?
Thanks !

[EDIT] : So far I can parse the email in John's inbox and extract the associated string containing the message. But what I want is the actual message (with the header and all), not just the string containing the message.

Comment: You'll have to match conversation participants (senders/receiver) and subjects. Sadly email has no nice counter that says I'm message 8 in this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail has a very nice IMAP extension to do this. I've never tried to use the objective-c libraries, though.

If you want to do this for one conversation, you need a message to start with. Any message in the conversation will do. First, you retrieve the X-GM-THRID of that message: `a uid fetch 23451345 x-gm-thrid`, which gives you a 64-bit number, perhaps 9876543876543444423. Next, you look for the other messages in the same conversation: `b uid search x-gm-thrid 9876543876543444423`, which gives you the UIDs of all messages in that conversation, and you're done.

If you want to do it for all the conversations in the inbox, you issue `c uid fetch 1:* x-gm-thrid`, which gives you a set of message-conversation tuples: "message 123 belongs to conversation 9876543876543".

If you want to order the messages within each conversation, the easiest way is probably to retrieve the `internaldate` item and sort by that. Gmail also has an `x-gm-msgid` but I haven't looked to see whether it's useful for sorting.

Comment: Perfect, I'll give it a try this WE and will let you know, but this seems like an excellent way to start. Thank you ! I will comment back as soon as I test. (Don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer..)

Comment: I think you're meant to accept the answer, not upvote it. Upvoting is for others. But I confess to a certain ignorance in these matters. Hope it helps, anyway.

Comment: Yes you're right ! Your answer guided me to get to the bottom of it, I'll post my answer later on with the use of objective-c lib.